# How to correctly use mask_zero=True for Keras Embedding with pre-trained weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word-embedding

I am confused about how to format my own pre-trained weights for Keras `Embedding` layer if I'm also setting `mask_zero=True`. Here's a concrete toy example.

Suppose I have a vocabulary of 4 words `[1,2,3,4]` and am using vector weights defined by:

```
weight[1]=[0.1,0.2]
weight[2]=[0.3,0.4]
weight[3]=[0.5,0.6]
weight[4]=[0.7,0.8]
```

I want to embed sentences of length up to 5 words, so I have to zero pad them before feeding them into the Embedding layer. I want to mask out the zeros so further layers don't use them.

Reading the Keras docs for Embedding, it says the 0 value can't be in my vocabulary.

> mask_zero: Whether or not the input value 0 is a special "padding"
>   value that should be masked out. This is useful when using recurrent
>   layers which may take variable length input. If this is True then all
>   subsequent layers in the model need to support masking or an exception
>   will be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a consequence, index 0
>   cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim should equal size of
>   vocabulary + 1).

So what I'm confused about is how to construct the weight array for the Embedding layer, since "index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary." If I build the weight array as

```
[[0.1,0.2],
 [0.3,0.4],
 [0.5,0.6],
 [0.7,0.8]]
```

then normally, word `1` would point to index 1, which in this case holds the weights for word `2`. Or is it that when you specify `mask_zero=True`, Keras internally makes it so that word `1` points to index 0? Alternatively, do you just prepend a vector of zeros in index zero, as follows?

```
[[0.0,0.0],
 [0.1,0.2],
 [0.3,0.4],
 [0.5,0.6],
 [0.7,0.8]]
```

This second option seems to me to put the zero into the vocabulary. In other words, I'm very confused. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're second approach is correct. You will want to construct your embedding layer in the following way

```
embedding = Embedding(
   output_dim=embedding_size,
   input_dim=vocabulary_size + 1,
   input_length=input_length,
   mask_zero=True,
   weights=[np.vstack((np.zeros((1, embedding_size)),
                       embedding_matrix))],
   name='embedding'
)(input_layer)
```

where `embedding_matrix` is the second matrix you provided.

You can see this by looking at the [implementation of keras' embedding](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/embeddings.py#L15) layer. Notably, how mask_zero is only used to *literally* mask the inputs

```
def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
    if not self.mask_zero:
        return None
    output_mask = K.not_equal(inputs, 0)
    return output_mask
```

thus the entire kernel is still multiplied by the input, meaning all indexes are shifted up by one.